# Zend App on host without mod_rewrite and no virtual hosts

Tags: php, zend-framework

I try to export my local developed app to a shared hoster environment. By doing this I figured out that either I could use mod_rewrite nor virutal hosts.
Now my question is a) how do I have to change my app to deploy it and b) how do I do it in a secure way by c) letting the URL looking as nice as possible.

Please be more specific as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698/php-zend-mvc-without-mod-rewrite) or provide an example like [here](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/).

Thank you!

**Local set-up (with mod_rewrite and virtual host):**

```
root
+-application
  +-configs
  +-controllers
  +-forms
  +-layouts
  +-models
  +-views
  +-Bootstrap.php
+-public
  +-css
  +-dl
  +-js
  +-img
  +-index.php
  +-.htaccess
+-library
  +-...
```

Comment: I'd better look for better host. Why? [http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=friendly+urls&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy&hl=pl&q=friendly+urls&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=6096dfcf6781ad76](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=friendly+urls&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy&hl=pl&q=friendly+urls&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=6096dfcf6781ad76)

Comment: Thank you but this is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rob Allen has an article as well about setup ZF with out mod_rewrite

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-urls-without-mod_rewrite/

Comment: Hm .. I read it before but thought there should be something from the framework itself now, because the post is from 2008. You think it is still the only way? Is it possible to use his class as a Front Controller Plug-in?

Comment: @lony: Yes it's the only way to go. ZF by default doesn't need mod_rewrite and the routers can extract parameters the normal way too. The example over there is to have a route that creates non-mod_rewrite urls and is a router, not a frontcontroller plugin.

Comment: Hm ..I tried the snipped from Rob, but I only get a blank white page. In the comments there is something written that the script has to be updated to a new Zend version. Has somebody already done this and it works?